# infinited loop with java selector

Tags: java, selector, nio

I am a new comer in Java, now I got puzzled with java nio selector, below are the code from the book of java network program 3rd,

```
package org.eclipse.java.socket.samples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class ChargenServer {
    public static int DEFAULT_PORT = 4321;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port;
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            port = DEFAULT_PORT;
        }
        System.out.println("Listening for connections on port " + port);
        byte[] rotation = new byte[95 * 2];
        for (byte i = ' '; i <= '~'; i++) {
            rotation[i - ' '] = i;
            rotation[i + 95 - ' '] = i;
        }
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel;
        Selector selector;
        try {
            serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            ServerSocket ss = serverChannel.socket();
            InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(port);
            ss.bind(address);
            serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            selector = Selector.open();
            serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                selector.select();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }            
            Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();
                try {
                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                        ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel) key
                                .channel();
                        SocketChannel client = server.accept();
                        System.out
                                .println("Accepted connection from " + client);
                        client.configureBlocking(false);
                        SelectionKey key2 = client.register(selector,
                                SelectionKey.
                                OP_WRITE);
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(74);
                        buffer.put(rotation, 0, 72);
                        buffer.put((byte) '\r');
                        buffer.put((byte) '\n');
                        buffer.flip();
                        key2.attach(buffer);
                    }
                    else if (key.isWritable()) {
                        SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();
                        if (!buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                            // Refill the buffer with the next line
                            buffer.rewind();
                            // Get the old first character
                            int first = buffer.get();
                            // Get ready to change the data in the buffer
                            buffer.rewind();
                            // Find the new first characters position in
                            // rotation
                            int position = first - ' ' + 1;
                            // copy the data from rotation into the buffer
                            buffer.put(rotation, position, 72);
                            // Store a line break at the end of the buffer
                            buffer.put((byte) '\r');
                            buffer.put((byte) '\n');
                            // Prepare the buffer for writing
                            buffer.flip();
                            buffer.compact();
                        }
                        client.write(buffer);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    key.cancel();
                    try {
                        key.channel().close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException cex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The server is quite simple, get a connection, then echo a serial letters to the clients,
but when i run it on my Ubuntu10.10 with

Java version "1.6.0_20"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.4) (6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1)

OpenJDK Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

I got a infinite loop, I really do not know why, help me please!

Thanks everybody, but i still be confused with selector, now let's make things more easy to show my confused, see the code:

```
package org.eclipse.java.socket.selector;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class SocketSelector {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create selector
        Selector selector = null;
        selector = Selector.open();
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(
                "localhost", 4321));
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
        /*
         * Let's begin select
         */
        while (true) {
            selector.select();
            System.out.println("Hello, selector!");
            Set readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator it = readyKeys.iterator();  
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey )it.next();
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    System.out.println("It's readable!");
                }
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in my understand, "selector.select()" wait a input event from remote server, then it.remove() remove this event, so the selector begin to wait for new event from remote server, so the client can get data from server with selector in a continuous way, but the result is looped again and again, the selector make no sense to the server's data,
why? 
Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: I suspect your connections are always ready to write, or its time to get the debugger out to see what is going on. Personally I use blocking with NIO rather than use a selector and it makes the code much simpler. (and can be faster)

Comment: Blocking is really simple, but when i need manage many connections, selector is a perfect choice rather than many threads.

Comment: you need to close connection with finally block

Comment: But i need a continuous connection...

Comment: you want to listen data on particuler port with socket connection..?

Comment: if there is no data on socket connection then why you want to open that connection ..? If there is no data on socket connection then it is meaningless to open connection ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three are multiple issues w/ the code, incl. not closing the selectors.

You need to register for `OP_WRITE` *only* if the write operation fails to write the entire Buffer, and unregister otherwise. Look at `interestedOps()`.

Generally, you need OP_READ in order to read from that channel.
Finally **ALWAYS** check http://bugs.sun.com before stackoverflow (it's one of my tracked bugs). Advise: don't use the same selector to accept/write.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4919127

cheers

Answer (score 2):

Once you have written everything you want (i.e., when the out-buffer is empty) you should remove the `OP_WRITE` interest flag.